# Cannot access localhost from chrome extension content script

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to alert a message from a webapplication hosted on iis using a chrome extension. My content script code is below.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var results = '';
  $.each(request, function (key, value) {
      results += key + ": " + value + '\n';
  });
  alert(results);
 });
```

This web application is also hosted in a remote server. the alert works well from a webpage on the remote server but it does not alert on my localhost. Below is a snippet of the manifest file.

```
   "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches":     ["http://localhost/WebApp/*","http://staging.mysite.com/WebApp/*"],
  "js": ["libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "results.js"]
}
],
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: i doubt you can match on localhost

Comment: You can match `localhost`. There's probably some other issue. Use the debugger, simplify the code, etc. Or link the entire extension zip here to test it.

Comment: My extension doesn't work on `http://localhost:8080/test.html` and I have `http://*/*` in the permissions, so @ZigMandel appears to be correct.